# Bind data to multiple ComboBoxes using xml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I need to write a program containing 4 comboboxes.

The **first** combobox contain a list of functions, each choice (any change in the index of the combobox) changes the contents of the **second** combobox.

The **second** combobox contains a list of functions, each choice (any change in the index of the combobox) changes the contents of the **third** combobox.

And so should I do the same to the rest of comboboxes.

I need to build a hierarchy in XML support that.

My program look like this

[image]
Any combination of four the combobox changes the `textbox` (I have about 900 combinations).

Any idea how to make the A hierarchy of the file so that each change in the index of combobox will change the rest of the comboboxes and change the  text in the `textbox` appropriate to the current combination?

And I need to understand the relationship between combobox's *selected index changed event handler function* to how am I supposed to take the information from the XML file.

Comment: I can answer your question. However, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I need some guidance,Idea, way of thinking, how an XML file should look like, that's all.

Comment: Thats **not**  how StackOverflow works. You'll have to do some research on your own before we'll help you. If you're not able to do so I'd guess you're out of luck.

Comment: I searched but did not find any solution how to build the file so it will fit in the hierarchy.
And next time before you come to the conclusion that I didn't looked hard enough, think again.
If that's not convenient for you, please find another place to complain.